# Mass renaming an image sequence

Tags: linux, file-io, terminal

I have a list of images sequences that requires renaming, it is basically adding in an extra underscore in the last under of the sequence.

Example.
sun_seq_img_001.jpg >>> sun_seq_img__001.jpg

However, when I try the following command `rename "_" "__"" *`, it is replacing the first underscore `sun__img_...` which is not what I wanted

I can try using `mv sun_seq_img_001.jpg sun_seq_img__001.jpg` but it is a hassle especially I am dealing with large sequences

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file names are just like you describe, then you should be able to do this:

```
rename img_ img__ *
```

Otherwise, you can use a `bash` script like this:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do mv "$i" "${i%_*}__${i##*_}" ; done
```

`${i%_*}` strips away the last `_` and the stuff after it.
`${i##*_}` strips away the last `_` and the stuff before it.